# Read Only Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have make a Data Flow in `SSIS` but in the Destination Field,

It is showing that 
cannot insert value in `Person_key` from `Participant_key` as Person_key is read only column.

Does anybody have workaround for that? Do I have to make changes in database or in SSIS only?

Comment: what is the datatype of the column Person_key? is the column defined as Identity?

Comment: Can you also post the full error?

Comment: And could you describe your task? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Probably executing [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT` for table with Person_key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) could do the trick.

Comment: Person_key is the primary key

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` flag just allows you to insert data with explicitely specified identity, which is useful when you transfer data from one table to another including identity. Just read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) link with more detailed explanation about `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`, it wirth reading if you're working with SSIS

Answer (score 0):

If it's an identity column and you don't need to specify specific values, just don't map anything to that column in your destination editor. That way it'll use the identity sequence number.